ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yolo_predictions'
I made object detection using yoloV8 with Visual Studio Code and streamlit as a webapp. An error occurred when I ran the 1_YOLO_for_image file in the program from yolo_predictions import YOLO_Pred
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yolo_predictions'
Even though I have put the yolo_prediction file in the same location.enter image description here
and when i run streamlit something error like this
enter image description here
this is my yolo_predictions.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import yaml
from yaml.loader import SafeLoader


class YOLO_Pred():
    def __init__(self,onnx_model,data_yaml):
        #load YAML 
        with open(data_yaml,mode='r') as f:
            data_yaml = yaml.load(f,Loader=SafeLoader)

        self.labels = data_yaml['names']
        self.nc = data_yaml['nc']

        #load YOLO Model 
        self.yolo = cv2.dnn.readNetFromONNX(onnx_model)
        self.yolo.setPreferableBackend(cv2.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_OPENCV)
        self.yolo.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CPU)

    def predictions(self,image):
        
        row, col, d = image.shape
        #get the YOLO prediction from the image 
        #step-1 convert image into square image (array)
        max_rc = max(row,col)
        input_image = np.zeros((max_rc,max_rc,3),dtype=np.uint8)
        input_image [0:row,0:col] = image
        #step-2: get prediction from square array
        INPUT_WH_YOLO = 640
        blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(input_image,1/255,(INPUT_WH_YOLO,INPUT_WH_YOLO),swapRB=True,crop=False)
        self.yolo.setInput(blob)
        preds = self.yolo.forward() #detection or prediction from YOLO


        #Non Maximum Supression
        #step-1: filter detection based on confidence (0,4) and probability score (0,8)
        detections = preds[0]
        boxes = []
        confidences = []
        classes = []

        # widht and height of the image (input_image)
        image_w, image_h = input_image.shape[:2]
        x_factor = image_w/INPUT_WH_YOLO
        y_factor = image_h/INPUT_WH_YOLO

        for i in range (len(detections)):
            row = detections[i]
            confidence = row[4] #confidence of detection on object
            if confidence > 0.4:
                class_score = row[5:].max() #maximum probability from 20 object
                class_id = row[5:].argmax() #get the index position at which max probability occur

                if class_score > 0.8:
                    cx, cy, w, h = row[0:4]
                    #construct bounding from four values
                    left = int((cx - 0.5*w)*x_factor)
                    top = int((cy - 0.5*w)*y_factor)
                    width = int(w*x_factor)
                    height = int(h*y_factor)

                    box = np.array([left,top,width,height])

                    #append values into the list
                    confidences.append(confidence)
                    boxes.append(box)
                    classes.append(class_id)

        #clean
        boxes_np = np.array(boxes).tolist()
        confidences_np = np.array(confidences).tolist()

        #NMS
        index = np.array(cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes_np,confidences_np,0.25,0.45)).flatten()
        #draw the bounding 
        aa=0
        bb=0
        cc=0 
        my_array=[]  
        for ind in index:
            #extract bounding box
            x,y,w,h = boxes_np[ind]
            bb_conf = int(confidences_np[ind]*100)
            classes_id = classes[ind]
            class_name = self.labels[classes_id]
            colors = self.generate_colors(classes_id)
            text = f'{class_name}: {bb_conf}%'

            if(class_name=='retak diagonal'):
                aa+=1
            if(class_name=='retak vertikal'):
                bb+=1
            if(class_name=='retak horizontal'):
                cc+=1

            cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),colors,2)
            cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y-10),(x+w,y),colors,-1)

            cv2.putText(image,text,(x,y-10),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,0.7,(0,0,0),1)

        my_array=[aa,bb,cc]
        return image,my_array
    
    def generate_colors(self,ID):
        np.random.seed(10)
        colors = np.random.randint(100,255,size=(self.nc,3)).tolist()
        return tuple(colors[ID])

and this is code 1_YOLO_for_image
import streamlit as st
from yolo_predictions import YOLO_Pred
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

st.set_page_config(page_title="YOLO Object Detection",
                   layout='wide',
                    page_icon='./images/object.png' )

st.title('WELCOME TO CRACK DETECTION FOR IMAGE')
st.write('Please Upload Image to Get Detections')

with st.spinner('Please wait while your model is loading'):
    yolo = YOLO_Pred(onnx_model='./models/bestie.onnx',
                    data_yaml='./models/configp.yaml')
    ##st.balloons()


def upload_image():
    #Upload Image
    image_file = st.file_uploader(label='Upload Image')
    if image_file is not None:
        size_mb = image_file.size/(1024**2)
        file_details ={"filename":image_file.name,
                    "filetype":image_file.type,
                    "filesize":"{:,.2f} MB".format(size_mb)}
        ##st.json(file_details)
        #validate file
        if file_details['filetype'] in ('image/png','image/jpeg'):
            st.success('VALID IMAGE file type (png or jpeg)')
            return {"file":image_file, 
                    "details":file_details}
        else:
            st.error('INVALID Image file type')
            st.error('Upload only png,jpg,jpeg')
            return None
        
def main():
    object = upload_image()

    if object:
        prediction = False
        image_obj = Image.open(object['file']).convert('RGB')
        

        col1 , col2 = st.columns(2)

        with col1:
            st.info('Preview of Image')
            st.image(image_obj)

        with col2:
            st.subheader('Chech below for file details')
            st.json(object['details'])
            button = st.button('Get Detection from YOLO')
            if button:
                with st.spinner("""
                Getting Objects from image. please wait
                                """):
                #below command will convert obj to array
                    image_array = np.array(image_obj)
                    pred_img= yolo.predictionss(image_array)
                    pred_img_obj = Image.fromarray(pred_img)

                     # Perform object detection using YOLO
                    #detections = yolo.predictions(image_obj)
                    #print(detection)
                    #detected_objects = {}
                    #for detection in detections:
                    #    object_class = detection['classes']
                    #    detected_objects[object_class] = detected_objects.get(object_class, 0) + 1

                    prediction = True

        if prediction:
            st.subheader("Prediction Image")
            st.caption("Object Detections Complete")
            st.image(pred_img_obj)
            st.write('Real-time Object Detection Results:')
           # st.write('Retak Diagonal =' +str(my_array[0]))
          #  st.write('Retak Vertikal =' +str(my_array[1]))
          #  st.write('Retak Horizontal =' +str(my_array[2])) 
            #for object_class, count in detected_objects.items():
            #    st.write(f'{object_class}: {count}')
           
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/Cb0Le.jpg)

seems like YOLO_predictions module and YOLO_for_image are not on the same path. in your screenshot YOLO_for_image.py is under 'PAGE' and YOLO_predictions is in outside PAGE

you are using virtual environment. move your module to same path. not only for actual path but also in virtual path too

it doesnot work
